# Correct stop loss and take profit in MQL4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I'm newbie in `mql4`. Suppose I buy a currency pair in price of 1000. `TP` is 1500 and `SL` is 800. What I want is:

**When prices goes up to 1300, I change SL to 1200**. In other words, when price reaches to 1300, it closes when price goes down to **1200** or goes up to **1500**. How can I code this?

My code for now looks like this:

```
int tiketbuy=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY, Lot,Ask, Slippage,  Ask-Distance,Ask+(2.5*Distance),NULL,1111,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [OrderModify](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordermodify) function